# Accessing class from variable within class

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example:

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = []


class Baz():
    pass


test = Foo()
test.bar.append(
    Baz()
)
```

Now that I have instantiated `Baz`, how can I access `test` from `Baz`?

Comment: You can't. You would need to manually tell each instance of `Baz` about `test`.

Comment: `Baz` has no reference to test.

Comment: @StephenRauch `Baz` doesn't have a reference to `test` because I don't know how to reference it. That's the question.

Comment: What do you need to do this for?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to give each `Baz` a reference to `test` if you wanted things to be set up like this:

```
class Baz():
    def __init__(self, test):
        self.test = test    

test = Foo()
test.bar.append(
    Baz(test)
```

Comment: You could also factory it and have BAZ append himself to test bar...